# Lodash break from map/reduce on error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

If I have a function like `_.transform`.

Somewhere within the `iteratee` function I encounter an error; how do I exit from the `_.transform` function?

i.e.

```
{
  try {
    fs.readFileSync('dog_pics');
  } catch(e) {
    return;
  }
}
```

What about `_.map`? Which expects `return` statements.

Comment: `_.transform` requires you to build a new result. Can we see the rest of your iteratee?

Comment: This is a hypothetical. I'm curious if there's a way to jump out of these functions if I need to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`_.transform` callback can return `false` in order to stop iterating.

From lodash examples:

```
_.transform([2, 3, 4], function(result, n) {
  result.push(n *= n);
  return n % 2 == 0;
});
// → [4, 9]
```

As you can see, iteration breaks on third step, when `n === 3`

`_.map` and `_.reduce` doesn't support iteration stopping

Comment: That's a nice/a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Since [_.transform](https://lodash.com/docs#transform) builds a new return object, returning without setting a pushing onto the result would allow you to "jump" out of that iteration.

(I haven't actually tested this code.)